# UITableView Header Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am setting the property of table, tableHeaderView to be hidden, this works and hides the tableHeaderView but i also want the table to move up and cover up the space that previously the tableHeaderView was occupying.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the `tableHeaderView` you need to do the following at the place where you want to hide the header,

```
[yourTableView setTableHeaderView:nil];
```

This will automatically remove the space which your header view was occupying.

Comment: awsome man, that one does the trick, fine solution man. Thanks

Comment: Welcome.. But, I guess, you missed the key word, **tableHeaderView** in your question.. Otherwise you would have got your answer very early.. Every one here thought that you are setting header in your table view's section..

Answer (score 1):

To omit the header and space, use:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: this method works for titleHeader, but my question means different from this answer.

Comment: My solution is for no text in the tableHeader, as well as normal spacing between sections. You may want to rephrase your question.

Comment: i have only one section, i have done this self.tableView.tableHeaderView.hidden = YES;   and now after that i want the UItableView to move up and take space of header also.

Comment: You do not need tableHeaderView.hidden=YES. If you do not want text or space in the table header, then my solution is how its done. My solution says if there is no text there is no extra space. Its not much simpler than this.

Answer (score 0):

for that the only thing you have to do is set the height of the header to 0.

Then even if you wont hide the header It will get hidden automatically

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section      
{
  return 0;
}
```

hAPPY iCODING...